# Why is an Apache server responding differently to my NodeJS vs Python requests?

Tags: python, node.js, apache, python-requests

I've been hitting a REST API for a website for months with the Python [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library without issue. It's on a private network that I have no control over. It also requires client certificate authentication, so the call looks something like:

```
r = requests.get('https://example.com/some/endpoint?param=something', cert=(key_path, cert_path), verify=ca_path)
```

Upon inspection of the request, I was able to see that the server initially replies with a `302` redirect code to another URI on the server in order to set an authentication cookie, and then redirects back to the resource I was requesting, which is then fulfilled successfully. Hakuna matata.

We've been standing up a new NodeJS server component and attempting to connect it to the same endpoint. I've tried with a few different libraries, and they all get identical results. Here's an example of one of my attempts using the popular [`got`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) library with the [`tough-cookie CookieJar`](https://github.com/salesforce/tough-cookie#cookiejar):

```
let opts = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(certPath),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync(caPath)],
    cookieJar: new CookieJar()
}

// Using Promise API here because I'm running on an older version of NodeJS which
// unfortunately doesn't have async/await :(
got('https://example.com/some/endpoint?param=something', opts).then((res) => {
    // ...
});
```

Strangely, the server responds with a `200` code, and an HTML page that basically says (and I'm paraphrasing of course):

*"You seem to have lost your session info, dude. Maybe your browser restarted after a plugin installation or something."*

It has embedded links to the site's login page. Unfortunately I can't copy and paste the output because everything's on a closed private network.

I can't for the life of me figure out *why* this server (which the response headers indicates is an Apache server), would be responding *differently* to Node's HTTP request vs Python's. I've even changed the HTTP request headers on both the `requests` and the `got` calls to be absolutely identical, to no avail. It *always* works for Python, and *never* works for Node.

This makes no sense to me. Is there anyone familiar with Python's `requests` library and Node's `HTTP` module who can identify the subtle differences in the way these might be connecting to the server that might be causing this issue? The server obviously seems to be able to distinguish between the two requests, even though the headers are identical. Anyone familiar with Apache have any ideas or things to look for which could shed light on the issue?

In case it's relevant, we're using **Python v3.6** and **Node v8.x** (Can't remember exactly which minor version... and unfortunately I can't access the machine at the moment, will update later)

Any suggestions? What other things can I try to get the requests to complete successfully in Node like they do in Python?

Comment: Are you sure Node is able to successfully read the cert files? Try dumping the contents in the console. Far as you described, the Apache server isn't receiving the certs.

Comment: @Nick Good suggestion. Yes, Node was able to successfully read the certs. When I printed out the `opts` object to the console I could see the `Buffer`s in the console.

Comment: That said, I didn't try making a request without the certs to see if the response was different. I'll give that a try when I get a chance.